# Categorising Google News by Type of Source

Tags: python, search, scrapy, categorization

For a current project, I have created a web scraper which is collecting the number of Google News results for a given search request.

For a closer analysis of the results, I would like to add a categorisation tool that allows to allocate the news by type (i.e. newspaper, blog, press release).

Is there any viable method to filter or allocate Google News results by type with help of scrapy/python (possibly also with the support of external tools or algorithms)? I would appreciate if someone has an idea.

```
import scrapy
import time

custom_settings = {
'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"
}

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    start_urls = ["https://www.google.com/search?&hl=en&q=3M&biw=1280&bih=607&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F01%2F2004%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2007&tbm=nws"]
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {
            'results': response.css('#resultStats::text')[0].extract(),
            'url': response.url,
        }
        yield item
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see on the page some articles *do* have classifiers such as "blog" or "press release": 
[image: google news]

Which means you can select them with xpath or css selectors. Something like `//h3/following-sibling::div[@class='slp']//text()` would do.

Comment: That would be an option - the algorithm would have to run through every single results page then though, which can be quite extensive...

Comment: Where would you get the information from otherwise? There's no algorithm to determine page content from given url. You can either grab what google gives you or connect to the article url and analyze the content yourself to determine whether it's a blog post or a news article (which won't be easy).

Comment: You are right - these are the most feasible methods I have come across so far. The indication provided by Google does however not seem very precise and the manual analysis would take months. Ideally, I am looking for a way to include the categorisation already in the search request, e.g. by looking for "Search Term + Blog"...